Получение (считывание) данных из ОЗУ через python
Как мне получить или прочитать данные хранящиеся в ОЗУ через python?Может быть есть подходящие библиотеки?!

Иными словами, вы хотите получить доступ к памяти всех/любых процессов, запущенных на данной машине?

да именно так..

Права root + /proc.. + /dev/kmem + /dev/mem и золотой ключик у вас в кармане
